Uniswap app on Sepolia testnet is not loading any tokens
'https://app.uniswap.org/add/ETH?chain=sepolia' is not allowing me to create any new Pools, or 'https://app.uniswap.org/swap' doesn't load up any possible tokens so swap.
I am connected with my Metamask Wallet, a sepoliaETH balance and several ERC20 tokens I created earlier.
But it is not possible for me to create a Pool with any token (doesn't matter if mine or any other tokens currently deployed on Sepolia).
Is there an easy fix or something I am forgetting? and is anyone encountering the same issue?

I have the same issue since 20 days ...tried in every way ...

Found the solution, here are the official Sepolia links from Uniswap:
https://github.com/Uniswap/interface/releases?page=3
That's what they said in their Discord:
"We do have Sepolia setup, although the Sepolia testnet is currently having issues in the Uniswap app. The developers are aware, and a fix is planned. Currently, the is no estimation for this completion."

How I m gonna add usdc to this its says it reads local storage but from where and how to add to it?

Uniswap app connected to testnet networks loads data from mainnet. At lease Ethereum and Polygon are affected.

IMO forking the mainnet is a better approach for your Uniswap issue on the Sepolia testnet. It allows you to work with real-world data and conditions, ensuring your token interactions and pool creations behave just like on the mainnet. This avoids the potential limitations and misconfigurations you might encounter with testnets, providing a more accurate and reliable testing environment.
